# Is it possible to use jlink on JDK 11 to make a runtime including the Java SE EE modules that were removed?

Tags: java, jlink

When I try to include java.xml.bind in my runtime I get an error message:

Error: automatic module cannot be used with jlink: java.activation from file:...[url to javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar in my gradle cache]

I'm using these artifacts on the module-path:

```
"javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.4.0"
"org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.4.0-b180830.0438"
```

It seems that with JDK 11, modules were removed but no fully-modularized replacements have been made available. So jlink can't make a runtime from them.

Why weren't the external replacements properly modularized, given that they were already modules in JDK 10?

Not only is java.activation still not modularized, it has a new module name, "jakarta.activation".  See https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jaf/#Latest_News
I believe that further breaks things, as everything that depends on that module will have to change again before jlink will run.

Comment: I don’t know about getting them via Gradle, but you can always use the java.activation.jmod and java.xml.bind.jmod from a Java 10 JDK.

Comment: The idea behind their removal was very well broadcasted by marking them `@Deprecated forRemoval` in Java9. Yet, I would say that's the least users could expect(modularisation), of a module moved out of JDK. As to the question seemingly specific to a target audience which shall include more developers and contributors of the JDK, rather than just consumers, I would suggest you move this to a mailing list or maybe comment and vote for such issues on the repositories where people have pointed this out already, [for e.g. this](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaf/issues/13#issuecomment-437807263).