# How can I bundle the JAXB runtime libraries with OpenJDK 11?

Tags: java, module, jaxb, java-11, java-module

**Background**:

In my organization there are a lot of Java based Windows desktop applications. In our proprietary software deployment system the applications don't contain an individual JRE / JDK. Rather a common JRE (so far Oracle 8 Java SE JRE) is deployed to the users machine, which is attached to the individual applications based on environment variables.

We would like to migrate the JRE from Oracle 8 Java SE JRE to OpenJDK 11 without having to modify the applications. From Java 8 to Java 11 various libraries got removed, e. g. JavaFX. Using the Java module system and the jlink tool, I can create my own proprietary JDK enhanced with OpenJFX:

```
jlink --module-path ..\mods;C:\Temp\javafx-jmods-11.0.2 --add-modules=ALL-MODULE-PATH,java.base,java.compiler,java.datatransfer,java.desktop,... --output C:\Temp\OpenJDK+OpenJFX
```

Applications, which need JavaFX can use this proprietary JDK without being changed.

When I try to apply the same method to the [latest beta of JAXB](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-ri/2.4.0-b180830.0438/jaxb-ri-2.4.0-b180830.0438.zip), I get the following error:

```
jlink --module-path ..\mods;C:\Temp\jaxb-ri-2.4.0-b180830.0438\jaxb-ri\mod --add-modules=java.xml.bind,java.base,java.compiler,java.datatransfer,java.desktop,java.instrument,... --output C:\Workspace\Java\OpenJDK_11.0.2_JFX_JAXB
Error: automatic module cannot be used with jlink: java.activation from file:///C:/Temp/jaxb-ri-2.4.0-b180830.0438/jaxb-ri/mod/javax.activation-api.jar
```

As per https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaf/issues/13, "*JAXB API uses activation-api as its dependency and is forced to use it as an automatic module or from classpath because of missing a module-info.java descriptor file.*"

Furtheron as per [Is it possible to use jlink on JDK 11 to make a runtime including the Java SE EE modules that were removed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53806586/is-it-possible-to-use-jlink-on-jdk-11-to-make-a-runtime-including-the-java-se-ee) I can bundle the module java.xml.bind using jlink from Java 10, which still contained it. Indeed jlink succeeds, if I add two modules from OpenJDK 10.0.2 to the module path:

```
jlink --module-path ..\mods;C:\Temp\jdk-10.0.2\jmods\java.xml.bind.jmod;C:\Temp\jdk-10.0.2\jmods\java.activation.jmod --add-modules=java.xml.bind, ...
```

But when I run my application with the generated JDK, I get errors like this:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2019-02-15 15:58:58.642
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultHeadlessContext(E4Application.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultContext(E4Application.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:614)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:399)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PostConstruct cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.100.v20170421-1418
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 24 more
```

Or this:

```
Feb. 15, 2019 2:49:03 NACHM. com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector <clinit>
 SEVERE: null
 java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(java.lang.String, [B, int, int, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.security.ProtectionDomain)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.xml.bind@10.0.2/com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector.<clinit>(Injector.java:182)
    at java.xml.bind@10.0.2/com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.AccessorInjector.prepare(AccessorInjector.java:66)
    at java.xml.bind@10.0.2/com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.OptimizedAccessorFactory.get(OptimizedAccessorFactory.java:164)
    at java.xml.bind@10.0.2/com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor$FieldReflection.optimize(Accessor.java:270)
    at java.xml.bind@10.0.2/com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayProperty.<init>(ArrayProperty.java:53)
    at java.xml.bind@10.0.2/com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.<init>(ArrayERProperty.java:73)
    at java.xml.bind@10.0.2/com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.<init>(ArrayElementProperty.java:85)
    at java.xml.bind@10.0.2/com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.<init>(ArrayElementNodeProperty.java:47)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.xml.bind@10.0.2/com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:113)
    at java.xml.bind@10.0.2/com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:166)
    at java.xml.bind@10.0.2/com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:499)
    at java.xml.bind@10.0.2/com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:316)
    at java.xml.bind@10.0.2/com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:124)
    at java.xml.bind@10.0.2/com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1141)
    at java.xml.bind@10.0.2/com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:150)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.xml.bind@10.0.2/javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:282)
    at java.xml.bind@10.0.2/javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:271)
    at java.xml.bind@10.0.2/javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:406)
    at java.xml.bind@10.0.2/javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:706)
    at java.xml.bind@10.0.2/javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:647)
    at com.xxx.build.automation.utils.internal.CategoryFileHandler.unMarshalFile(CategoryFileHandler.java:17)
    at com.xxx.build.automation.utils.common.GetComponentName.doExecuteInternal(GetComponentName.java:89)
    at com.xxx.build.automation.utils.common.GetComponentName.execute(GetComponentName.java:72)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1337)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1306)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1189)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:758)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:257)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:104)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(java.lang.String, [B, int, int, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.security.ProtectionDomain)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2109)
    at java.xml.bind@10.0.2/com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector$3.run(Injector.java:186)
    at java.xml.bind@10.0.2/com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector$3.run(Injector.java:182)
    ... 48 more
```

**Question**:

Is there any possibility, how I can bundle the JAXB libraries with OpenJDK 11?

**Hint**:

- I am aware on approaches how to tackle the removed JAXB at build time for a classic Java application build: [How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException in Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j) or [Include JAXB using Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566620/include-jaxb-using-maven). But if I don't want to touch the deployed application binaries, build time solution doesn't help me in this scenario.

Comment: Perhaps you can patch the module `java.activation` by adding `module-info.class` to make it explicit. Then `jlink` should run fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try to include these two dependencies:

```
    implementation group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.0'
    implementation group: 'org.glassfish.jaxb', name: 'jaxb-runtime'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `javax` API modules, it is usually not possible to upgrade from jdk8 without modifying you application. Some implementations like `com.sun` packages where physically removed since jdk9 and you have to add them as dependency.

You are also running into the `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException` so the current available implementation is not compatible anymore with the `javax` API from jdk10

Answer (score 0):

My organization finally gave in to modify the applications at compile time. It is not the solution I was searching for, but at least it works for us.

Answer (score 0):

JAXB has been removed from JDK starting with version 11, you would need to add it as you add all other dependencies.

Example for maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>${jaxb.api.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
    <version>${jaxb.api.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>${jaxb.api.version}</version>
</dependency>
```